# tikz problem (non-continuous function)

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs

I want to plot a function x^3/(x^2-1) but it doesn't work.

```
\documentclass{article}    
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}[domain=-5:5,smooth]
    \draw[->] (-5,0) -- (5,0) node[right] {$x$}; 
    \draw[->] (0,-5) -- (0,5) node[above] {$y$};
    \draw [color=blue, thick] plot ({\x},{pow(\x,3)/(pow(\x,2)-1)});
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

It does something like this. It should be non-continuous function, not this.

[image: function]

How to fix it? Thanks.

Comment: The output of this are only axis and a caption.

Comment: I've added a little bit of information on how to add your own labels for ticks and such to my answer. If this doesn't help feel free to ask.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If using `pgfplots` would be ok for you then you could avoid such problems. Instead of the `standalone` class you can, of course, use any other documentclass you like.

**Edit:** I pimped my example a little. If you want to label some points or add function definitions etc. to your plot you can do this like in any other `tikzpicture`: creating nodes and drawing works in the same way as usual. To make your life easy you can access the in-plot coordinates via `axis cs:`, so if you want to create a node at the in-plot point x=1 and y=0 you can use something like `\node at (axis cs:1,0) {$x=1$};`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        restrict y to domain=-5:5,
        samples=1000,
        ticks=none,
        xmin = -5, xmax = 5,
        ymin = -5, ymax = 5,
        unbounded coords=jump,
        axis x line=middle,
        axis y line=middle,
        xlabel={$x$},
        ylabel={$y$},
        x label style={
          at={(axis cs:5.02,0)},
          anchor=west,
        },
        every axis y label/.style={
          at={(axis cs:0,5.02)},
          anchor=south
        },
        legend style={
          at={(axis cs:-5.2,5)},
          anchor=west, font=\scriptsize
        }
        ]

      \addplot[color=blue, mark=none, domain=-5:5] {x^3)/((x^2) - 1)};
      \addlegendentry[blue]{$f(x)=\frac{x^3}{x^2 - 1}$}
      \draw[dashed] ({axis cs:1,0}|-{rel axis cs:0,1}) -- ({axis cs:1,0}|-{rel axis cs:0,0});
      \draw[dashed] ({axis cs:-1,0}|-{rel axis cs:0,1}) -- ({axis cs:-1,0}|-{rel axis cs:0,0});
      \node[below right, font=\scriptsize] at (axis cs:1,0) {$x=1$};
      \node[below left, font=\scriptsize] at (axis cs:-1,0) {$x=-1$};
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit:**

Here is a pure `tikz` solution. It's not very elegant but in case one doesn't want to use `pgfplots` it might be a good starting point.

```
 \documentclass{standalone}    
 \usepackage{tikz}

 \begin{document}

   \begin{tikzpicture}[smooth, scale=0.5]
        \pgfmathsetmacro\ymax{pow(1.05,3)/(pow(1.05,2)-1)}
        \draw[->] (-10,0) -- (10,0) node[right] {$x$}; 
        \draw[->] (0,-\ymax) -- (0,\ymax) node[above] {$y$};
        \draw [color=blue, thick, domain=-10:-1.05, samples=200] plot ({\x},{pow(\x,3)/(pow(\x,2)-1)});
        \draw [color=blue, thick, domain=-0.96:0.96, samples=200] plot ({\x},{pow(\x,3)/(pow(\x,2)-1)});
        \draw [color=blue, thick, domain=1.05:10, samples=200] plot ({\x},{pow(\x,3)/(pow(\x,2)-1)});
        \draw [color=black, dashed] (-1, -\ymax) -- (-1, \ymax);
        \draw [color=black, dashed] (1, -\ymax) -- (1, \ymax);

   \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I use my documentclass and I also need similar looking graphs.

Comment: @goLK here is just using the `standalone` class to generate the image.  The image wont be affected if you use the `article` class instead.  You can always remove the x and y tick marks and add `y` and `x` if that is what you mean by similar looking.

Comment: @goLK I improved the look of my example a little. Is your problem with the documentclass solved by dustin's comment?

Comment: Thanks but "! Package tikz Error: Unknown coordinate system 'ticklabel*'.".

Comment: @goLK Strange, for me it's compiling fine. Have you tried compiling just my example or does the problem arise in your real document?

Comment: It's only directly your piece of code.

Comment: @goLK Do you use a recent LaTeX distribution? Maybe it is too old. You can also try to leave out the lines with `every axis label`. They seem to be the source of the problem and since they only influence the placement of the axis labels it should still look ok if you leave them out.

Comment: Great, it was helpful! Thanks. Can I ask you for an explanation how to add captions to asymptotes and points on axis?

Comment: What kind of captions and points on axis would you like to have? And for the problem with `every axis label`: you could try to change the respective code to `x label style={
          at={(axis cs:5.02,0)},
          anchor=west,
        },
        every axis y label/.style={
          at={(axis cs:0,5.02)},
          anchor=south
        }`.
This might work for you.

Comment: I would like to have numbers by intersection of asymptote and axis X and also equations by function and asymptotes.

Comment: @goLK I added a legend containing the function definition. And the axis labels for the asymptote line are also there. Or did you have something different in mind?

Comment: No, that is great! Thx!